# How to jam a jet to shoot it down/capture it?

Tags: technology, military, hacking

I am writing a near-future technology-based sci-fi about a war that would take place in the Mediterranean sea. At the very beginning, I want a French Rafale pilot patrolling and teaching a Greek pilot next to the Turk border to have his jet jammed by electronic means as they fly over a recovery area of one Israelian submarine captured by pirates that want to sell the device to Iranians. So, in order to make this part realistic, I was wondering if and how it was possible to jam a Rafale to the point of shooting it down and capturing its crew?

Comment: Why does it need to be "jammed"? Planes with ecm are not immune to attack. Why not a heat seeking missile or even a lucky gun shot? Single bullet through the rudders hydraulic actuator mount or a trim pads jackscrew and they'll enter a spin and need to eject...

Comment: Are you trying to a) jam the jet so it can't transmit/receive/pick something up on radar, b) force it to land and recover it, or c) force the crew (if that's the word; isn't the Rafale a one-seater?) to eject and capture them? These are very different mission profiles.

Comment: @Cadence option c! There are both one and two seaters versions of it!

Comment: The simplest jammer is to return the same freq back like an echo so that the radar cannot calculate your position from the pulse signal and emitted signal ratio, that said you can copy a scene from Spaceball to fire an actual giant bottle of jam at high velocity to knock the plane down! ;D

Answer (score 1):

**Your device hacks the Direct Voice Input**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_voice_input

> Direct voice input (DVI) (sometimes called voice input control (VIC))
> is a style of human–machine interaction "HMI" in which the user makes
> voice commands to issue instructions to the machine.
>
> DVI has been introduced into the cockpits of several modern military
> aircraft, such as the Eurofighter Typhoon, the Lockheed Martin F-35
> Lightning II, the Dassault Rafale and the Saab JAS 39 Gripen.

The device captured by the pirates uses a backdoor in the aftermarket satellite link installed in these planes to hack the direct voice input.  Physical or voice input from the pilot is made difficult or bypassed and the pirate gives commands that puts the plane thru high-G maneuvers that incapacitate the pilot.  This will be exciting if the Greek trainee is in an adjacent plane which is not affected because he will see and hear it all.  The French pilot is not immediately incapacitated and during the process he shouts a lot in French.

The pirate then uses voice input to quickly land and capture the plane before the pilot recovers.  This would also be fun to write because you could have the pirate actually speaking his commands.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the voice command would allow sudden automated manoeuvres without independent confirmation from the pilot.  It's still a neat idea, but my first question when writing software for such a thing would be "this can't incapacitate the pilot, can it?"

Comment: @jdunlop - I agree coders should make sure their code does not wrest control from the pilot and kill him.    But that still happens! https://www.forbes.com/sites/taylorarmerding/2018/11/20/hard-questions-raised-when-a-software-glitch-takes-down-an-airliner/?sh=6e0fde547b1d

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Willik's Answer, you can hack the direct voice input from a distance [using lasers to cause a distant object to vibrate](https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/security/a29689494/hackers-lasers-alexa-google-home/), simulating the voice.

That link shows a demo of someone using a laser to simulate the voice command: "OK google open the garage door". This allows someone to enter your house without a key.

The message your hackers will send will be dependant on what's in the manuals of these fighters, which I couldn't find online. Also it'd probably be in french. So I'm just making stuff up here:

- "Ok google, reset the IFF public key" (causes all friendly planes to see you as a bad guy - so they attack you).
- "OK google, tune approach ILS to 123.45, and activate auto land" (cause it to auto-land at an airport by frequency).
- "OK google, eject me". I doubt this is actually hooked up, but hands-free ejection makes sense for high G spins, so it may be a possibility.